# SQLAlchemy unpack enum values

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, enums, sqlalchemy

I have a model name called A having an enum column a_c.

When I try to fetch a_c values am getting enum objects as results.

```
session.query(A.a_c).filter(A.id==1).all()
```

If I try to caste also it returns only keys.

```
session.query(A.a_c.cast(String)).filter(A.id==1).all()
```

Actually, I need an enum value as output.

```
class enum_1(enum.enum):
     type_1 = Type 1
     type_2 = Type 2
```

am expecting results `Type 1` not `type_1` or object.

Comment: Are you using the stdlib `Enum`?  If you are, you should have `enum.Enum` and `'Type 1'`.